# Acceptable way to store encrypted password

Tags: android, encryption, aes, password-encryption, firebase-remote-config

I am thinking about a way I can "try to protect" my application data.

Initially I was doing the following:

I have an encryption key that I use to encrypt and decrypt the data received, as well as what will be stored, I used firebase for the backend.

Basically something like this:

```
 private String encriptar(String datos, String password) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = generateKey(password);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] datosEncriptadosBytes = cipher.doFinal(datos.getBytes());
        String datosEncriptadosString = Base64.encodeToString(datosEncriptadosBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return datosEncriptadosString;
    }

    private String desencriptar(String datos, String password) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = generateKey(password);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] datosDescoficados = Base64.decode(datos, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] datosDesencriptadosByte = cipher.doFinal(datosDescoficados);
        String datosDesencriptadosString = new String(datosDesencriptadosByte);
        return datosDesencriptadosString;
    }


    private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] key = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        return secretKey;
    }
```

Well, you can see that in all three methods the **password value** is required for all methods, encryption, decryption and to generate the key.

I had planned to save this password as "Remote confing" in firebase and get it when I use it, but there are many calls to the server. The other option is to store it locally, but if I do it this way, the password would be plain text in a sharedpreferences, for example.

I am somewhat confused with how to approach this.

I am a rookie on the subject (as you may have seen) and would appreciate knowing if my approach is correct in keeping the key and what you would advise me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You really need to define *exactly* what you are hoping to protect yourself from.  Throwing a bunch of cryptography around is more or less meaningless until you know exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  This isn't obvious in your question - would you mind clarifying?

Comment: In general there is **nothing** you can do in your application that can't also be done by an attacker who reverse engineers your application. Nothing. Nada. Negaroni. The best you can do is make it painful enough that the attacker gives up and goes after another target.

Comment: Of course, I want to use the encryption to, for example, store the Keys APIs of YouTube, Instagram, etc.

I have the api key in an already encrypted string.

For example "gs6hw82hd5g28wbs8wjo>=="
When I need to use the apikey, I will decrypt it with the password and it will be readable again to send it to the webservice.

The password must be declared in the Code. I mean that password

Comment: Right.  You don't need to cryptography then, you need authorization - a mechanism to control access to that key.  Usually this is implemented by having a back-end service that can make requests using your API keys on behalf of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase takes care of the encryption for you. The data you send in the network does not go through in plain text. To secure your database, consider adding Security Rules.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: I am confused with the answer. If I get a value from the real-time database of firebase and save it as a String within a shared preference, when displaying the log in the console logcat, it is shown as plain text that can be read without problem.

Sorry for not understanding you, I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Firebase encrypts your data while in-traffic (in the network) and decrypts it as it arrives on the client's. Hence, you can read it in plain text.
Generally, I would advice against manually storing passwords and have a Firebase Authentication service setup. 
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Also, if you're worried about your API keys, you can consider storing them in an environment config on your server and accessing them through Cloud Functions. This may be a little complicated to setup. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env